# How can I enable / disable a button to validate a form where there is an ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a form that I am trying to validate. I want to validate that all text fields contain some text. the array that I am adding in the ng-repeat may vary. If the form is correct, the button must be enabled. if it is not correct, it must be disabled.

How can I do it?

```
<body ng-controller="Channels">
  <div ng-repeat="item in aCandidatos">
      <input type='text' ng-model="item.votos" required>
  </div>
  <button ng-disabled="!item.votos">
   send
  </button> 
</body>

[
  { "nombre": "Candidato","votos":""},
  { "nombre": "Candidato2","votos":""}
];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/vnq7g4q3/

Comment: When you say "some text" do you mean some specific text or just any text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the the `$invalid` marker on AngularJS forms to check for basic HTML5 validations (such as some/any data exists). In the example below, the validation occurs based on the wiring around the `Form` and the `required` attribute:

```
<body ng-controller="Channels">
  <form name="votosForm" novalidate>
    <div ng-repeat="item in aCandidatos">
      <input type='text' ng-model="item.votos" required>
    </div>
    <button ng-disabled="votosForm.$invalid">
     send
    </button>
  </form>
</body>
```

Note that I did not have to make any corresponding change to the Angular `Controller`.

Answer (score 1):

**Use this approach:**

Basically, the function `invalidVotes` checks for some empty vote.

```
function Channels($scope) {
   $scope.aCandidatos=
    [
      { "nombre": "Candidato","votos":""},
      { "nombre": "Candidato2","votos":""}
    ];

    $scope.invalidVotes = function() {
      return Object.values($scope.aCandidatos).some(c => !c.votos || c.votos.trim() === '');
    }
}
```

```js
function Channels($scope) {
  $scope.aCandidatos = [{
      "nombre": "Candidato",
      "votos": ""
    },
    {
      "nombre": "Candidato2",
      "votos": ""
    }
  ];

  $scope.invalidVotes = function() {
    return Object.values($scope.aCandidatos).some(c => !c.votos || c.votos.trim() === '');
  }
}

angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Channels', Channels);

angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.5/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="Channels">
  <div ng-repeat="item in aCandidatos">
    <input type='text' ng-model="item.votos" required>
  </div>
  <button ng-disabled="invalidVotes()">
     send
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work:

```
 <body ng-controller="Channels">
    <div ng-repeat="item in aCandidatos">
        <input type='text' ng-model="item.votos" required>
    </div>
    <button ng-disabled="isDisabled()">
     send
    </button> 
  </body>

function Channels($scope) {
   $scope.aCandidatos=
      [
        { "nombre": "Candidato","votos":""},
        { "nombre": "Candidato2","votos":""}

      ];
    $scope.isDisabled=()=>{
            let isDisabled=(($scope.aCandidatos.filter((item)=>item.votos=="")).length!=0)?true:false
            return isDisabled;
    }
}

angular.module('app', [])
  .controller('Channels', Channels);

angular.bootstrap(document.body, ['app']);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using AngularJS's built-in form validation rather than HTML5's. To handle the repeated fields `<ng-form>` is perfect, allowing you to isolate the scope and provide individual validation messages where appropriate. This will also let you use a single submit button if you want, allowing users to submit all of the votes at once rather than one by one.

```
<section ng-controller="Channels">
    <form name="candidatesForm" novalidate>
        <ng-form ng-repeat="user in aCandidatos" name="voteForm">
            <label>{{ user.nombre }}s Votos</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="votos" ng-model="user.votos" required>
            <p class="help-block text-danger" ng-show="voteForm.votos.$invalid">Votos is required.</p>
        </ng-form>

        <button type="submit" ng-disabled="candidatesForm.$invalid">Send</button>
    </form>
</section>
```

Here are a few additional details on the specific changes I've added here and why:

- `novalidate` added to the form disabled the default HTML5 handling of validation
- Giving a form a name provides us with AngularJS's built-in form validation on the $scope
- `<ng-form>` let's us create isolated scope's for each repeated form, letting us validation them individually
- Add `type="submit"` to the button will trigger a proper form submit